# Arabicfont and URL link selection

Tags: luatex, arabic

I have some links with Arabic characters which are not properly displayed  in my current font. Therefore I select Arabic language before using the link. The MWE looks like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,naustrian]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[tracking=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10,final]{microtype} % have some better layout of individual chars
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,bidi=basic]{babel}
\directlua{luaotfload.add_fallback("fntFallback",{
"DejaVu Sans:mode=harf",
"NotoColorEmoji:mode=harf"})}
\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}% Ligatures=TeX ist set automatically (used to have the automatics ligatures of TeX)
[RawFeature={fallback=fntFallback}
,SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}% fonts for small caps
]
\usepackage{xurl}
\urlstyle{same} 
\babelprovide[import=ar]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz, Language=Default]{Amiri}
\usepackage[pdfa, unicode]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item 
    Wasserknappheit - with more text - as link, 
    {\selectlanguage{arabic}\href{https://www.alsumaria.tv/news/محليات/352690/ماء-النجف-توضح-أسباب-شح-المياه-في-المحافظة}{\nolinkurl{https://www.aaaralsumaria.tv/news/محليات/352690/ماء-النجف-توضح-أسباب-شح-المياه-في-المحافظة}}}%
    , additional text;
    \item 
        Wasserknappheit - with more text - but the text is not as link %
            \href{https://www.alsumaria.tv/news/محليات/352690/ماء-النجف-توضح-أسباب-شح-المياه-في-المحافظة}{\nolinkurl{https://www.alsumaria.tv/news/محليات/352690/ماء-النجف-توضح-أسباب-شح-المياه-في-المحافظة}}%
    , additional text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

and this compiles to

[image]

as one could see the link is created for more or less the whole item - WHEN selecting the language. When I don't select the language the problem does NOT appear.

Is there a way to set Arabic language and have a hyperlink ONLY for the `\href` item?

Running with

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/TeX Live for SUSE Linux)  (format=lualatex 2023.1.15)  20 JAN 2023 09:46
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an engine problem, it doesn't handle the link area correctly if there is direction change. So there is not much hyperref or babel can do currently. But I wrote to the luatex list and reported the problem.

As demonstration of the problem compile this with luatex:

```
\hsize=5cm \parskip=1em

OK: 
{abc \textdir TRT
\pdfextension startlink
    attr {/Border[0 0 1]}
    user{
        /Subtype/Link/A<</S/URI/URI(blub)>>
        } 
 x  y y y  z       
\pdfextension endlink  
abc 
} end 


Wrong:
{abc \textdir TRT
\pdfextension startlink
    attr {/Border[0 0 1]}
    user{
        /Subtype/Link/A<</S/URI/URI(blub)>>
        } 
 x  y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y z       
\pdfextension endlink   
abc
} end     

\pardir TRT \textdir TRT
OK:
\pdfextension startlink
    attr {/Border[0 0 1]}
    user{
        /Subtype/Link/A<</S/URI/URI(blub)>>
        } 
 x  y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y z       
\pdfextension endlink   
end   
\bye
```

you then get this:

[image]

Comment: thx for testing and narrowing it down.

Comment: Can you please a link to the issue (if you have raised one)? Its more or less related to checking once in a while if the issue might be resolved - or not.

Comment: the issue is here https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2023-January/006730.html